# Decoupling 3 way switch

Tags: ceiling-fan, light, multiway-switch

I currently have a hallway with two light fixtures, both of which are controlled by the 3 same light switches in different spots in the house. I want to  replace one of the light fixtures with a small ceiling fan and decouple the light switches so one switch controls the fan and the other two continue to control the existing light fix.

How would I go about changing 1 3-way lighting circuit to 2 separate circuits for lighting (with 3-way switching) and a fan?

Comment: Where are the three switches located in regards to doorways, top and bottom of stairs, etc.

Comment: Yes, where are the switches located, and can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved pelase?

Comment: Thanks for the help. The hallway is at the top of a set of stairs. One switch is at the bottom of the stairs, one is directly at the top of stairs and the other is on the opposite side of the hallway (closest to the fixture I want to replace). The two light fixtures are about 10 ft apart.  I can post pics of the inside of the boxes tomorrow.

Comment: "How big a project is it" is fairly opinion based and could get your question closed. I changed it to ask "how do I do it", which is fairly fact based and should remain open & get good answers. Once you've found out how and what's involved, _you_ make the decision to carry on, nix it, or hire it out. Please take a minute to take the [tour] to see why this is important.